# Opengl surface rendering issue

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rendering

I just started loading some obj files and render it with opengl. When I render these meshes I get this result (see pictures).
I think its some kind of depth problem but i cant figure it out by myself.
Thats the parameters for rendering:

```
    // Dark blue background
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

// Enable depth test
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

// Cull triangles which normal is not towards the camera
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

I used this Tutorial code as template. https://code.google.com/p/opengl-tutorial-org/source/browse/#hg%2Ftutorial08_basic_shading
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you clear the depth & color buffers anywhere?

Comment: Can you show your draw loop code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is simple, you are doing FRONT or BACK culling.

And the object file contains CCW(Counter-Clock-Wise) or CW (Clock-Wise) cordinates, so written from left to right or right to left.
Your openGL code is expecting it in the other way round, so it hides the surfaces which you are looking backward on.

To check this solves your problem, just take out the `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);`
As this exactly seems to be producing the problem.

Additionally you can use `glCullFace(ENUM);` where ENUM has to be `GL_FRONT` or `GL_BACK`.
If you don't in at least one of both cases can't see your mesh (means in both cases: `GL_FRONT` or `GL_BACK` your just seeing the partial mesh) , thats  a problem with your code of interpreting the .obj. or the .obj uses not strict surface vectors. (A mix of CCW and CW)

Answer (score 3):

I am actually unsure what you mean, however glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); and then GL_CULL_FACE(GL_BACK); will cull out or remove the back face of the object. This greatly reduces the lag while rendering objects, and only makes a difference if you are inside or "behind" the object.

Also, have you tried glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); before your render code?